# Où est-ce que je peux regarder la télé en français sur Internet ?

Tags: ressources, culture, télévision

Je veux regarder la télé en français, et ça ne me dérange pas de payer des frais si nécessaire.

Est-ce que vous avez des idées ?

Answer (score 3):

[TV5 monde](http://www.tv5mondeplus.com) est disponible sur internet également. Elle a l’avantage de présenter un éventail plus large de la francophonie et de proposer des sous-titres pour la plupart des programmes (pour passer outre les particularités locales, tant en matière d’accent que de vocabulaire).

Answer (score 2):

Les chaînes publiques sont en clair : France2, France 3, France 4, France 5, Arte, France Ô sont aussi accessibles librement par Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Il est également possible d'accéder à toutes sortes de contenue gratuitement et légalement en regardant les replays disponibles sur les sites tels que W9 replay, M6 replay, TF1 replay.

Il y a également beaucoup de contenu sur youtube, par exemple: "Reportage #THEME#"

Answer (score 0):

Au Canada, il y a Radio-Canada, Tou.tv, Télé-Québec, TVA... Pour des idées d'émissions télé, vous pouvez voir ici : https://regardsurlefrancais.com/category/culture/television/

Answer (score 0):

La plupart des chaînes sont disponibles sur internet.

https://www.tf1.fr/ (il faut s'incrire, c'est gratuit), http://www.france2.fr/, (existe aussi pour 3,4,5), http://www.6play.fr pour M6 et http://www.6play.fr/w9 pour W9, http://www.canalplus.fr/ (la chaîne est payant mais il y a un créneau ou les programmes sont gratuits ("en clair")), https://www.tf1.fr/tmc, ...

Quasiment toutes les "grosses" chaînes ont un site qui diffusent leur émissions, qu'on peut regarder en "replay" après leur date de diffusion. Après si tu veux savoir quoi regarder, c'est une autre question.

NOTE: Il est possible que certaines chaînes ne soient pas disponible en dehors de la France. Il y a des plugins de navigateurs qui permettent de contourner ça en te mettant dans le pays de ton choix, ZenMate ou BrowserVPN par exemple).